# one to one chat with socket golang

Tags: go, websocket

I have a shopping application where users post availability and other users can find them and join their availability.

I now have a chat service which is essentially for chatting. i.e a customer may chat with the shopper to confirm details or other things. This chat is supposed to be one to one. So there could be 5 customers enquiring about a shopping post, I want the chat to be unique in the sense that chat from customer A regarding a shopping should be separate from that from customerB about the same shopping. The shopper should be able to see the chats and respond.

This is what I have currently, but this seems to broadcast message to everyone in the with the reference. I just want the message sent from specific sender recieved by shopper wthout others having access to the chat.

"client.go"

```
type Client struct {
    Conn           *websocket.Conn
    ChatRepository chat.ChatRepository
    Message        chan *Message
    ID             string `json:"id"`
    Reference      string `json:"reference"`
    Username       string `json:"username"`
    Sender         string `json:"sender"`
    Recipient      string `json:"recipient"`
}

type Message struct {
    Content   string `json:"content"`
    Reference string `json:"reference"`
    // Username  string `json:"username"`
    Sender string `json:"sender"`
}

func (c *Client) writeMessage() {
    defer func() {
        c.Conn.Close()
    }()

    for {
        message, ok := <-c.Message
        if !ok {
            return
        }
        uuid, err := uuid.NewV4()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to generate UUID: %v", err)
        }
        chatMessage := chat.ChatMessage{
            ID:     uuid.String(),
            Sender: message.Sender,
            // Recipient: recipient,
            Timestamp: time.Now(),
            Content:   message.Content,
        }
        if c.Sender == message.Sender {
            _, errx := c.ChatRepository.AddMessage(message.Reference, chatMessage)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("failed to generate UUID: %v", errx)
            }
        }
        c.Conn.WriteJSON(chatMessage)
    }
}

func (c *Client) readMessage(hub *Hub) {
    defer func() {
        hub.Unregister <- c
        c.Conn.Close()
    }()

    for {
        _, m, err := c.Conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err, websocket.CloseGoingAway, websocket.CloseAbnormalClosure) {
                log.Printf("error: %v", err)
            }
            break
        }

        msg := &Message{
            Content:   string(m),
            Reference: c.Reference,
            Sender:    c.Sender,
            // Username:  c.Username,
        }

        hub.Broadcast <- msg
    }
}
```

"hub.go"

```
type Room struct {
    ID      string             `json:"id"`
    Name    string             `json:"name"`
    Clients map[string]*Client `json:"clients"`
}

type Hub struct {
    Rooms      map[string]*Room
    Register   chan *Client
    Unregister chan *Client
    Broadcast  chan *Message
    emmiter    events.Emitter
}

func NewHub(emmiter events.Emitter) *Hub {
    return &Hub{
        Rooms:      make(map[string]*Room),
        Register:   make(chan *Client),
        Unregister: make(chan *Client),
        Broadcast:  make(chan *Message, 5),
        emmiter:    emmiter,
    }
}

func (h *Hub) Run() {
    for {
        select {
        case cl := <-h.Register:
            if _, ok := h.Rooms[cl.Reference]; ok {
                r := h.Rooms[cl.Reference]

                if _, ok := r.Clients[cl.ID]; !ok {
                    r.Clients[cl.ID] = cl
                }

            }
        case cl := <-h.Unregister:
            if _, ok := h.Rooms[cl.Reference]; ok {
                if _, ok := h.Rooms[cl.Reference].Clients[cl.ID]; ok {
                    // if len(h.Rooms[cl.Reference].Clients) != 0 {
                    //  h.Broadcast <- &Message{
                    //      Content:   "user left the chat",
                    //      Reference: cl.Reference,
                    //      Username:  cl.Username,
                    //  }
                    // }

                    delete(h.Rooms[cl.Reference].Clients, cl.ID)
                    close(cl.Message)
                }
            }

        case m := <-h.Broadcast:
            if _, ok := h.Rooms[m.Reference]; ok {
                for _, cl := range h.Rooms[m.Reference].Clients {
                    cl.Message <- m
                    if m.Sender != cl.Recipient {
                        notifications.SendPush(h.emmiter, cl.Recipient, fmt.Sprintf("New message from %v", cl.Username), m.Content)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"handler.go"

```
type Handler struct {
    hub            *Hub
    chatRepository chat.ChatRepository
}

func NewHandler(h *Hub, chatRepository chat.ChatRepository) *Handler {
    return &Handler{
        hub:            h,
        chatRepository: chatRepository,
    }
}

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    },
}

func (h *Handler) JoinRoom(c *gin.Context) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(c.Writer, c.Request, nil)
    if err != nil {
        utils.HandleError(c, nil, "error creating chat connection", http.StatusBadGateway)
        return
    }

    reference := c.Param("reference")
    sender := c.Query("sender")
    username := c.Query("username")
    recipient := c.Query("recipient")

    if reference == "" || sender == "" || username == "" || recipient == "" {
        utils.HandleError(c, nil, "required parameters missing", http.StatusBadGateway)
        return
    }
    if _, ok := h.hub.Rooms[reference]; !ok {
        // Room doesn't exist, handle accordingly
        _, err1 := h.chatRepository.GetChatHistory(reference)
        if err1 != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to retrieve chat history: %s", err1)
            errx := h.chatRepository.CreateChat(reference)
            if errx != nil {
                utils.HandleError(c, nil, "error storing connection", http.StatusBadGateway)
                return
            }
        }
        h.hub.Rooms[reference] = &Room{
            ID:      reference,
            Name:    sender,
            Clients: make(map[string]*Client),
        }
    }

    cl := &Client{
        Conn:           conn,
        ChatRepository: h.chatRepository,
        Message:        make(chan *Message, 10),
        ID:             sender,
        Reference:      reference,
        Sender:         sender,
        Username:       username,
        Recipient:      recipient,
    }

    h.hub.Register <- cl
    go cl.writeMessage()
    cl.readMessage(h.hub)
}
```

"routes.go"

```
hub := ws.NewHub(events.NewEventEmitter(conn))
    wsHandler := ws.NewHandler(hub, pr.NewChatRepository(db, client))
    go hub.Run()
v1.GET("/chat/ws/:reference", g.Guard([]string{"user", "admin", "dispatcher"}, nil), wsHandler.JoinRoom)
```

```
"chat.model.go"

    type Chat struct {
        ID        string        `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
        Reference string        `json:"reference" bson:"reference"`
        Messages  []ChatMessage `json:"messages" bson:"messages"`
    }
    type ChatMessage struct {
        ID        string    `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
        Sender    string    `json:"sender" bson:"sender,omitempty"`
        Timestamp time.Time `json:"timestamp" bson:"timestamp,omitempty"`
        Content   string    `json:"content" bson:"content,omitempty"`
    }
```

Comment: Yes, so once a shopper creates an availability that they are available, there's a unique ID created for that post. Customers should be able to chat privately with the shopper after viewing the post.

Comment: @CharlieTumahai you can think of it as carpooling. you post that you are carpooling and different riders can chat you up.

Comment: No, I want it to be 1-1. The reference is the postID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason your code is broadcasting messages to everyone in the room with the same reference is the way you handle messages in the `Broadcast` channel of your `Hub`. In the current implementation, when a message is sent, it is forwarded to every client in the same room (i.e., with the same reference). That is done in the `Run` method of the `Hub`:

```golang
case m := <-h.Broadcast:
    if _, ok := h.Rooms[m.Reference]; ok {
        for _, cl := range h.Rooms[m.Reference].Clients {
            cl.Message <- m
            ...
```

> I want it to be 1-1. The reference is the postID

If the `reference` is the `postID`, and you want 1-to-1 communication between the shopper (the one who made the availability post) and each customer, then you will need to make sure each chat is uniquely identifiable.

The unique key for each chat session should be a combination of the `postID` (`reference`) and the customer's ID (`sender`). That ensures that each customer has a unique chat session with the shopper for each post.

You can then update your `Client` struct to have a `ChatID` which is a combination of the `Reference` and `Sender`.

```golang
type Client struct {
    ...
    ChatID string `json:"chat_id"`
}
```

And you can update your `Hub` to manage a map of chat sessions (identified by the `ChatID`) instead of rooms.

```golang
type Hub struct {
    Chats      map[string]*Chat
    ...
}
```

With each `Chat` being a structure like:

```golang
type Chat struct {
    Shopper *Client
    Customer *Client
}
```

To handle messages, when a customer sends a message, it goes to the shopper, and when the shopper replies, it goes to the customer. The routing can be done using the `ChatID`.

For instance, in your `Broadcast` logic:

```golang
case m := <-h.Broadcast:
    chat, ok := h.Chats[m.ChatID]
    if ok {
        if m.Sender == chat.Customer.ID {
            // Message is from customer to shopper
            chat.Shopper.Message <- m
        } else if m.Sender == chat.Shopper.ID {
            // Message is from shopper to customer
            chat.Customer.Message <- m
        }
    }
```

The `m` variable is of type `*Message`, which does not have the `ChatID` field.
To fix this, you should consider adding a `ChatID` field to the `Message` struct.

First, let's modify the `Message` struct:

```golang
type Message struct {
    Content string `json:"content"`
    ChatID  string `json:"chat_id"`
    Sender  string `json:"sender"`
}
```

Then, when you construct a new `Message` inside the `readMessage` method of the `Client`:

```golang
msg := &Message{
    Content:   string(m),
    ChatID:    c.ChatID,
    Sender:    c.Sender,
}
```

When initializing a chat:

```golang
chatID := reference + "_" + sender

cl := &Client{
    ...
    ChatID: chatID,
}

// If the chat session does not exist, create it.
if _, ok := h.hub.Chats[chatID]; !ok {
    h.hub.Chats[chatID] = &Chat{
        Customer: cl,
        Shopper: nil, // That will be set when the shopper joins.
    }
} else {
    // That assumes only the customer or the shopper can join, not both at the same time.
    if h.hub.Chats[chatID].Shopper == nil {
        h.hub.Chats[chatID].Shopper = cl
    } else {
        h.hub.Chats[chatID].Customer = cl
    }
}
```

Warning: This is just a basic framework for the feature, but it does not account for additional complexities, like handling cases where either the customer or the shopper may have multiple devices, ensuring robust error handling, and more.